# Using Eigen objects in Python

Tags: c++, python, eigen

What resources are there for using Eigen objects in Python?  I'm aware of PyEigen, but I can't seem to find any new development on it.  Is there anything else?

Comment: what new development do you think is necessary?  Eigenvalue problems and algorithms have been around for a long time.  The code might be stable.

Comment: @duffymo The PyEigen [website](https://launchpad.net/pyeigen) says the project is in pre-alpha state and it's last update was almost two years ago. Also [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) is a large linear algebra library dealing with much more than just eigenvalues.

Comment: It shouldn't take more than a few hours to create your own set of linear algebra functions -- even less if you only need limited functionality. Which eigenvector/value operations do you need to perform?

Comment: I didn't mean eigenvalues and eigen vectors, I meant "Eigen", the linear algebra system for C++.

Comment: why not use numpy instead? It's the library of choice in python.

Comment: @P3trus: I was using boost.python and wanted interoperability when I wrote this question.  numpy objects would require conversion at the seams.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on a wrapper for the sparse parts of Eigen, available here: https://github.com/charanpald/SpPy. It's beta stage currently.